# differential equation with linear coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I Have an problem with solving differential equation. My solutions is other than in book from equation from.

Equation has form:

$$ (3x + 2y +1) \,dx - (3x+2y -1)  = 0$$

In first step I'm doing substitution:

$$ u = 3x + 2y +1 $$
$$ u - 2 = 3x + 2y -1  $$
$$ du = 3dx + 2\,dy $$
$$ dx = \frac{du - 2\,dy} 3 $$

So my equation now has a form:

$$ u \left(\frac{du-2y}{3}\right) - (u-2)\,dy = 0 $$

After simplification I'm obtaining:

$$ u\,du  - 5u\,dy + 6\,dy = 0$$
$$ u\,du +(-5u+6)\,dy = 0 $$

Now I'm dividing equation both sides by $ (-5u+6) $

And I'm obtaining equation with separable variables:

$$ \frac{u}{-5u + 6} \, du + dy = 0 $$

Because:

$$ \int \frac{u}{-5u+6} =  \frac{1}{25} (-5u + 6 - 6 \ln|-5u + 6|) + C$$

So I'm obtaining solution:

$$ y + \frac{1}{25}(-5u + 6 -6\ln|-5u+6|) = C $$

And after substitution $u = 3x+2y+1$:

$$ y + \frac{1}{25} (-15x - 10y +1 - 6 \ln|-15x-10+1|) = C $$
After simplification:
$$  \frac{3}{5}(y-x) + \frac{1}{25} - \frac{6}{25} \ln|-15x-10y+1| =C $$

At the end I'Multiplying the equation by $25$:

$$ 15(y-x) + 1 - 6 ln| -15x -10y +1| = C  $$

Is it correct answer?  In book from equations from there is an answer:

$$ \ln|15x + 10y -1 | + \frac{5}{2}(x-y) = C $$

I don't know what's wrong with my solution. I will be greatfull for help. Best regards.

Comment: Those are the same solutions, divide your equation by $-6$

Comment: So, how could I transform my solution to solution from book?

Comment: $dy$ is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$15(y-x) + 1 - 6 \ln| -15x -10y +1| = C$$
$$\frac{15(y-x) + 1 - 6 \ln| -15x -10y +1|}{-6} = C$$
$$\frac{5}{2}(x-y) + \ln|15x + 10y - 1| = C$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand you used also absolute value property: 
$|a| = |-a|$?

Comment: Yes I did, I hope that that was clear.

Comment: Yes, very clear. Thanks ;)